# Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state. Choose "Crash"

Tags: xcode, logic, internal

I am using my MacAir for development in conjunction with my iMac.  MacAir is Lion, iMac is snow lep

My MacAir is not allowing me to open xcode.  It continues to give me this error.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.

```
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-       1938/Framework/Utilities/IBFoundationAdditions.m:2247
Details:  Both arguments are required
Function: NSString *IBRelativePath(NSString *, NSString *)
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x4026acba0>{name = (null), num = 8}
Hints:   None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent it, it is a logic error in Xcode, eventually Apple will get it fixed. Xcode 4.x it a work-ion-progress that has a lot of nasty edges yet.

I have had good luck (usually) clicking "Continue", sometimes a dozen times in one after another and had Xcode continue. Quitting and re-launching Xcode sometimes improves things.

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448642/how-can-i-prevent-xcode-from-doing-this).

There are two uninstall scripts in /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools and /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder Try them prior to an new install.

You should file a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: problem is-- it wont let me use xcode at all :( clicking continue only crashes the program as well. i've tried re-installing a few times as well. nothing seems to work

Comment: in other words, when I launch the xcode application this error pops up automatically and I can do anything but crash.

Comment: Xcode 4.3 I assume. There are two uninstall scripts in /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools and /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder Try them prior to an new install. YOu can file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: filed a bug report, good suggestion on that.  will the uninstall scripts ork with 4.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on Xcode 4.2. I clicked on the "Continue" option when presented. Then I noticed an Interface Builder window open. The 'IDEInterfaceBuilder' assertion error is a clue that it has something to do with Interface Builder. So I closed all Interface Builder windows, and selected a source file to display in the main view instead.

I also noticed Xcode was running a couple of background tasks (re-indexing and another which I cannot recall; I had previously removed the xcuserdata folder for this project and opened Xcode, let it crash, and then restored the original xcuserdata folder; I'm not sure if this helped things along or not). After letting the two tasks finish, I quit Xcode, restarted, and everything worked as normal.

It is clearly a bug in Xcode, but it appears to be recoverable. In summary, try:

1. Click 'Continue' when presented in the popup;
2. Close any interface builder windows, and select a source file in the main view instead;
3. Restart Xcode

If this doesn't work, first try temporarily moving the xcuserdata folder out of the project folder, restart Xcode, quit Xcode, and then move the xcuserdata folder back, and restart Xcode, before following the previous process.

Already reported the bug to Apple.